# Disable some of the columns in Datasheet view

Tags: datasheet

Is there any way to disable just few of the columns in Datasheet view?
I would like to show all the columns, but to allow the clients to edit only some of them, and in order to prevent any mistakes, to disable the others?

Thanks.
BN

Answer (score 2):

You can define your "read only" columns as rich text fields. These columns cannot be edited in the datasheet view. If you're into programming you can create your own custom field types (like custom number, currency...) Custom field types cannot be edited in the datasheet view either.

Comment: In SharePoint 2010, this works for ENHANCED rich text fields, not regular rich text fields.